# Getting name of variable in r

Tags: r

```
a<-1:10

anyfunction<-function(data)

{

*********some function***********

}

>anyfunction(data=a)
```

output i want to get something like this

```
a

***value processed by function***
```

i want to print whatever the function does under the name of 'a' (here 'a' can be any variable name). any way to get this in R ?

one more thing i want to add to make this post clear is that i want to extract the name of variable as the row names of the output data

somethings like

```
anyfunction(data=a)
a ****output generate by function****        #here 'a' represents row names of the output
```

## sample example

```
myfunction<-function(data)
{
data=data+1
return(data)
}


a<-1:4
>myfunction(data=a)
```

## Expected output

```
a  2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Only matrices and data.frames have row names. I won't invest any more time into this until you have made it *crystal clear* what the desired output is. Until then I vote to close as unclear and delete my answer.

Comment: @Roland Hope now this is clear to you. It doesn't matter to me what kind of form the output carry whether it will be a matrix or dataframe . I just want to get a clear output like above as i mentioned

Comment: So you want the "row name" and the variable name to be the same?    Your code as presented is neither matrix nor dataframe so it can't have a rowname.  It is really hard to know what you are trying to achieve. Are you ultimately going to be supplying variables with many different names? Will this always be as above or might it be as part of an `apply` or in a loop?

Comment: @Elin i am trying to extract variable name and put that name into the row name of the output . i dont want to apply loop as it slow down when applied over large dataset in R. I also want to make sure that our output doesnt look likes comment as  suggested

Comment: So you are never going to do this for any variable besides a?    As stated rowname is not a concept that works for class integer which is what you have in your sample.

Comment: @Elin i have reached to my solution . i am just improving it once i make sure that it looks good i will post that . I am stucking at somewhere in text extraction process . my solution right now is not able to handle the data when it is carrying '$' in the argument . 
myfunction(data=a) #works fine 
myfunction(data=a$something) #giving error 
but when i assigned b<-a$something 
and run myfunction(data=b) #works fine

Comment: You can't have a be both an integer array and a dataframe.

Comment: @Elin yes you are right. I converted that into an array and give it rownames

Answer (score 2):

Last try:

Create an S3-class with a print method.

```
anyfunction<-function(data){
  res <- data + 1
  attr(res, "var") <- deparse(substitute(data))
  class(res) <- c("strange", class(res))
  res
}

print.strange <- function(x) {
  cat(attr(x, "var"), x, "\n")
}

anyfunction(a)
# a 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
```

Comment: Wouldn't `deparse(substitute(data))` be better? Try `anyfunction(1:10)` and compare output.

Comment: here it is displayed as a comment . i want this 'a' as a row names .@Roland

Comment: Well, why didn't you say so in your question?

Comment: @Roland sorry for inconvenience due to improper conveying of message

Comment: @Roland thank you for your efforts but i think still the interface of the output is still not so clear . 
i want something like 
 first line - a 
   second line- 55
or better a 55